# Using vim's make command with a makefile that runs make on subdirectories

Tags: vim, makefile

I have a project setup that has multiple sub-projects all with their own make files. There is a master make file in the main directory that cd's into each project and runs make in the proper order.

The makefile command looks like this:

```
sub-project/sub-project.a:
    cd sub-project ; make
```

The problem I have is that when I run make in vim and an error is reported, vim tries to open the file based on the relative path from inside whatever project had the error. Is there any way to have vim get the relative path from the root directory instead of the sub-project directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your makefile is reporting when it enters and leaves the subdirectories, as follows:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/projects/projectname/subdir1'
[... compile commands ...]
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/projects/projectname/subdir1'
```

In my experience, vim will parse this portion of the output to find the correct paths for the files with errors.  Also in my (frustrated) experience as of a few years ago, without the messages vim has no idea where to look for the files referenced by the error messages.

Note that this works even with recursive subdirectory building, as in this example:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/projects/projectname/subdir1'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/username/projects/projectname/subdir1/blah'
[... compile commands ...]
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/username/projects/projectname/subdir1/blah'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/projects/projectname/subdir1'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. I had made the makefile Silent with my own custom output to make the output cleaner. As soon as I took Silent out, vim started working as expected.

Comment: @drewag: I agree that silent is nice... but if you do so, add a similar output back.  That was the same one that caused me fits before.  Fortunately, when using vim I can easily skip over the extra stuff make outputs, and go directly to the errors, so I'm less picky about that now.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a while as I was convinced something was wrong in my recursive build-system as I recently made some changes there too. Thanks to this post I was able to pin-point the issue @Caleb: It turns out that you're absolutely right, vim will parse those strings and keep track of the build out-put. BUT (at least in my case) only if the locale is "correct". My solution to the problem was adding export LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8 in .env which I always have anyway. Not sure if this is an error in vim (surely vim should behave the same no mater how locale is set).

Answer (score 2):

`:make -w` is good enough to generate the directory listing that is important for vim to understand the current directory being compiled.